# How can I address textboxes in windows forms by their number?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

So I want to have around 12 text boxes (later on I will also add 12 picture boxes below) that will have the name of the product in them. However, while there is no option for there to be more than 12 products in the catalog, there can be less.

To save space, I thought I will create a cycle, that checks every loop if there are products left in the catalog, and if there is, it assigns the product to a textbox[i].

So basically, I would like to be able to address textBox1 as textBox[1], textBox2 as textBox[2] and so on.

I tried doing it like

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[] array = { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };
```

But it seems like I can only create such an object in from initialization, and when created there it seems to be unacessible anywhere else, even in the same form, so I can call the function to display only once when the form is initialized, and I would like to call the display method every time someone buys anything

Comment: what code do you have so far? You'd need to make the textbox array a class variable if you wanted it accessed elsewhere. If you posted the code, I could see where you're going wrong, all I can do is assume how you've done it

Comment: After `InitializeComponent();` you can write the code it should be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your textboxes are numbered consistently you access them through the Controls property of the form or container they're in.  You can use their name directly:

```
for(int i = 0; i<12;i++)
{
     this.Controls["textBox"+i.ToString()].Text = "Something";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

What about using a List?

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox> { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };
```

For this you'll need a reference to System.Collections.Generic.

After that you can access the textboxes with their number in the list:

```
textboxes[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the 12 textboxes added at design time you can do this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<TextBox> textboxes; //As a member of the class to be accesible everywhere in the class.
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textboxes = new List<TextBox> { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, ... }; //Just to be sure they are already created.
    }
```

And then you can acces to them by their index in the list `textboxes[i]` from any method of your form class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable of array or list

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[] TxtArray;
```

Then after initalization in your form constructor

```
InitializeComponent();
```

You can add up the line like

```
TxtArray = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, ... };
```