# Access a pictureBox by its number/index

Tags: c#, indexing, picturebox

I was wondering, if it is possible to access the pictureBox by its number. I asked a similar question before, and was given a great answer, but it was about textBoxes, and it seems that it doesnt work for pictureBoxes. Here is how it works with textBoxes:

```
this.Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()].Text = allProducts;
```

Can I access the pictureBox[i] in some similar matter? Thank you.

EDIT: To someone who suggested the post of textBox, I already mentioned that the same way did not work for pictureBox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I address textboxes in windows forms by their number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733855/how-can-i-address-textboxes-in-windows-forms-by-their-number)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't accessing textboxes by their number.  You are accessing them by their name, which happens to include a number.  You can do the same for any UI control, including PictureBox controls, if its name includes a number at the end.

You already have working code.  Just change the name.

For example

```
this.Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()].Text = allProducts;
```

could also be

```
this.Controls["pictureBox" + i.ToString()].Text = allProducts;
```

or even

```
this.Controls["MyKeshaThemedCustomControl" + i.ToString()].Text = allProducts;
```

Your code isn't type-specific.  It works with any control as long as it inherits from [Windows.Forms.Controls.Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx).  They all have a Text property, so your code is even type-safe! The only thing limiting you here is your naming convention, and your ability to stick to it.

If you need to access some property that is specific to a PictureBox (such as Image), you can do something like this:

```
var p = this.Controls["pictureBox" + i.ToString()].Text as PictureBox;
if (p == null) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Late binding is a B*!");
p.Image = GetImage();
```

If you are pretty sure you'll never get `i` wrong (or if you don't care about the messy exception) you can shorten it to

```
((PictureBox)this.Controls["pictureBox" + i.ToString()]).Image = GetImage();
```

Comment: That might be, but the property I am looking for is .image, not .text, and .image is pictureBox specific. Since I assume the program only realizes that I am actually referring to pictureBox during compilation, before it visual studio says it is an error,because this.Controls doesnt have the property .image.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will do what you want in a type safe manner

```
var myPicBox = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "pictureBox" + i.ToString());
```

It would traverse over all controls and filter out picture boxes and then find one ending with index. If it fails you will get a null. You may modify the code to work with many other types controls. For example, if you are looking for text box it would be ..

```
var myTextBox = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "textBox" + i.ToString());
```

Comment: So in this case, I could just treat myPicBox as pictureBox class object? If so, that is exactly what I am looking for, going to give it a try before accepting the answer just to make sure.

Comment: Yep, what you get is a strongly typed object of the class you specified, in this case the PictureBox. Visual studio will even offer you intellysence code completion on myPicBox